# Converting a React Class Component to Function Component

Tags: reactjs

I have build a small application using class component and it's working fine also.
While I convert that application to function component to use react hooks, it's giving me error.
Please check and let me know where it went wrong.

function component

```
import React ,{useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Counters from './component/counters';
import Navbar from './component/navbar';

function App(props) {

  const initialState = [
    { id: 1, value: 0 },
    { id: 2, value: 10 },
    { id: 3, value: 20 },
    { id: 4, value: 30 },
  ];

  const [counters, setCounters] = useState(initialState);

const handleIncrement = (counter) => {
    // const counters = [...counters];
    // const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    // counters[index] = { ...counter };
    // counters[index].value++;
    setCounters({ counter : counter.value +1 });
  };

  const handleDecrement = (counter) => {
//     // const counters = [...counters];
//     const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
//     counters[index] = { ...counter };
//     counters[index].value--;
//     setCounters({ counters });
   };

   const handleDelete = (counterId) => {
  //   const counters = counters.filter((c) => c.id !== counterId);
  //   setCounters({ counters });
   };

    return (
      <div className="container">
        {/* <Navbar totalCounters={counters.reduce((a,c)=>a + c.value,0 )}/> */}
        <Navbar totalCounters={counters.filter((c) => c.value > 0).count()}/>
        <Counters 
            counters={counters}
            onIncrement={handleIncrement}
            onDecrement={handleDecrement}
            onDelete={handleDelete} 
            />
      </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

class component

```
import './App.css';
import Counters from './component/counters';
import Navbar from './component/navbar';
import React from 'react';


class App  extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 0 },
      { id: 2, value: 10 },
      { id: 3, value: 20 },
      { id: 4, value: 30 },
    ],
  };

  handleIncrement = (counter) => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counters[index].value++;
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  handleDecrement = (counter) => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counters[index].value--;
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  handleDelete = (counterId) => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.filter((c) => c.id !== counterId);
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  render() { 
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Navbar totalCounters={this.state.counters.reduce((a,c)=>a + c.value,0)}/>
        <Counters 
            counters={this.state.counters}
            onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
            onDecrement={this.handleDecrement}
            onDelete={this.handleDelete} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In case, if you want to see the full code then just let me know.

Comment: Can you also include the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is your `counters` state is an array but you are mutating the state invariant to be an object in your handlers.

## Solution

App - Use a functional state update to map the `counters` array from the previous state to the next state, using the `id` to match the specific `counter` you want to increment/decrement/delete. This shallow copies the previous array. Notice also that the counter being updated is also shallow copied into a new object reference. When deleting a counter you are correct to use `.filter` to remove the specific element and return a new array.

```
function App(props) {
  const initialState = [
    { id: 1, value: 0 },
    { id: 2, value: 10 },
    { id: 3, value: 20 },
    { id: 4, value: 30 },
  ];

  const [counters, setCounters] = useState(initialState);

  const handleIncrement = (id) => {
    setCounters(counters => counters.map(counter => counter.id === id
     ? {
       ...counter,
       value: counter.value + 1,
     }
     : counter
    ));
  };

  const handleDecrement = (id) => {
    setCounters(counters => counters.map(counter => counter.id === id
     ? {
       ...counter,
       value: counter.value - 1,
     }
     : counter
    ));
  };

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    setCounters(counters => counters.filter((c) => c.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Navbar totalCounters={counters.filter((c) => c.value > 0).count()}/>
      <Counters 
        counters={counters}
        onIncrement={handleIncrement}
        onDecrement={handleDecrement}
        onDelete={handleDelete} 
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Counters - pass the counter id to the handlers

```
class Counters extends Component {
  render() {
    const { onIncrement, onDecrement, onDelete, counters } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {counters.map((counter) => (
          <Counter
            key={counter.id}
            counter={counter}
            onIncrement={() => {
              onIncrement(counter.id);
            }}
            onDecrement={() => {
              onDecrement(counter.id);
            }}
            onDelete={() => {
              onDelete(counter.id);
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Counter - since the `id` is closed in callback scope above just call the event handlers

```
class Counter extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className={this.getBadge()}>{this.getCount()}</span>

        <button
          className="btn btn-secondary m-2"
          onClick={this.props.onIncrement}
        >
          Increment
        </button>

        <button
          className="btn btn-secondary m-2"
          onClick={this.props.onDecrement}
        >
          Decrement
        </button>

        <button className="btn btn-danger m-2" onClick={this.props.onDelete}>
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit converting-a-react-class-component-to-function-component]

Comment: Thanks, it works. still I have to spent time how you did it. But Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `handleIncrement()` function, you're setting an object, when the `setCounters` method is expecting an array of objects.

You can use [ES6 destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Also note the object key should be the id not the object.

I expect the below to fix the error.

`setCounters([...counters, { counter.id : counter.value +1 }]);`

And I believe below is the implementation you're looking for.

```
otherCounters = counters.filter(c => c.id != counter.id)
setCounters([...otherCounters, { counter.id : counter.value +1 }])
```

---

**EDIT**: One thing I noticed in your `counters.jsx` and `counter.jsx` is that you're calling a function with variables that do not expect one.

From `counters.jsx`

```
<Counter
  ...
  // onIncrement of "Counter" (the 1st onIncrement on the left) 
  // is a function that do not expect a variable.
  onIncrement={() => {onIncrement(counter);}} 
/>
```

From `counter.jsx`

```
<button>
  ...
  // "onIncrement" is called with "this.props.counter". However this "onIncrement" is not expecting a variable.
  onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement(this.props.counter)} 
</button>
```

For the correct syntax, you can change either, but as example you can change `counter.jsx` to

```
<button>
  ...
  onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement()}
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ziwon, seems like code is giving error before running.

Comment: @Sanju, what's the exact error you're getting? Also, if the error is related to props, including the implementation of "Counters" helps too.

Comment: https://github.com/kunalgo/CounterApp  Please find the complete class component code here. @ziwon

Comment: getting counters.filter() is not a function.

Comment: You underlying component has an issue. Check the edited answer. For 'counters.filter()', You can comment it out to see if the code works first.

Answer (score 0):

In functional component on react when you wanna make state you must be use `useState`, you can follow my code here:

```
import './App.css';
import Counters from './component/counters';
import Navbar from './component/navbar';
import { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [countersState, setCountersState] = useState([
    { id: 1, value: 0 },
    { id: 2, value: 10 },
    { id: 3, value: 20 },
    { id: 4, value: 30 },
  ]);

  const handleIncrement = (counter) => {
    const counters = countersState
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    setCountersState(counters);
  };

  const handleDecrement = (counter) => {
    const counters = countersState
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    console.log(index)
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counters[index].value--;
    setCountersState(counters);
  };

  const handleDelete = (counterId) => {
    const counters = countersState.filter((c) => c.id !== counterId);
    setCountersState(counters)
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Navbar totalCounters={this.state.counters.reduce((a,c)=>a + c.value,0)}/>
      <Counters 
          counters={countersState}
          onIncrement={handleIncrement}
          onDecrement={handleDecrement}
          onDelete={handleDelete} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```